# If a SELECT "string" INTO var1 with a WHERE return no lines, does the string still get moved into var1?

Tags: sql, variables, select

```
MOVE "Y"   TO :LKG-RETURN
EXEC SQL                                
    SELECT "N"                          
    INTO :LKG-RETURN              
    FROM SOME_TABLE                      
    WHERE SOME_COLUMN = :SOME_VAR  
END-EXEC.
```

This is a part of a SQLCOBOL program where I need to check some variable in a database to see if the main program must run or not a job. By default I put "Y" into the return value but if the select return lines the job must not be run, so I put "N" into it. My question is:

If the select return 0 lines (which mean the job must be run), does it still move "N" to :LKG-RETURN? If it does, what could be my options to achieve the desired result?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it takes time to setup a test where I work and this job take about 2 hours to run, so I must be sure, check and double check my stuff before performing a test.

Comment: Your work has no testing / development environment?  You can't set up a test table and try it on a tiny data set?  What if your code is perfect, except for a single typo?  Surely you have some ability to test?

Comment: I got the luck to get the wonderful Messy-Job-That-Collect-Data-From-Everywhere-To-Call-Tons-Many-Other-Jobs-But-Stop-If-One-Of-These-Jobs-Do-Not-Receive-Correct-Data that got created in the late 80's where no norms were set and by today about 50 differents programmers added something to it. Setting up a test with my own data would take about a whole day to collect the right datas.

If i could test it first, I would not be here asking about it.

Comment: I've added an answer that may or may not be useful to you.  But you don't need to test your code against a live table:  Create a table with 1 record and test against that.  The `CASE WHEN EXISTS` option, however, may execute faster against larger datasets (depending on indexes, unqiueness of the field, etc, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The normal SQL behaviour would be that the value is NOT returned.  but I've never used SQLCOBOL to be able to test this.  And whenever I have even the remotest hesitation, I test.

In the absence of the ability to test, this will always return a value...

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO :LKG-RETURN              
FROM SOME_TABLE                      
WHERE SOME_COLUMN = :SOME_VAR  

-- 0 = no hits
```

Or possibly...

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_COLUMN = :SOME_VAR)
       THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
```

But, seriously, you need to find a way to test developments in your work environment.

I do not envy how difficult it must be where you work.  I hope this works out for you.